# Linux Debian. How to start vlan that work with Open vSwitch?

Tags: linux, debian

sorry for my English

Customer have server Linux Debian with some Wi-Fi Portal software.
It is have interface vlan100 with ip 10.21.126.59. We had access and could ping this interface.
But after rebooting server, we couldn't ping vlan100.

[/etc/network/interfaces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0hh2.jpg).

And it was shown in ifconfig But after rebooting not, because it is down.

I tried to UP vlan100 via [ifup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZyv1.jpg) vlan100. It return error [ifup vlan100](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJHfM.png)

How can I UP this vlan. My knowledge about OVS is - 0.
Help please

some(not full) history of engineer who configured server:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpM5X.jpg)
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yODob.jpg)
[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRpih.jpg)
[4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4st64.jpg)
[5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3k92j.jpg)

Comment: What's the output of the `systemctl status openvswitch-switch.service` command? That service should be started on bootup.

Comment: @FerencWágner  thanks for your answer. Tomorrow I will try this and respond

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed **vlan** package?

```
dpkg --list | grep vlan
```

You can try add `auto vlan100` statement to your /etc/network/interfaces and then reboot networking